# How do I find the lowest numbers in a square table, only one per column and one per row

Tags: algorithm

I'll elaborate.

Say I have a 2D array of numbers, same number of columns as rows (n), so n*n values in total.

I want to find the n numbers that have the lowest sum total. I am only allowed to take one number from each row, and one number from each column.

So I'll make an easy example, here's a table where n=3

```
1 2 3
3 1 2
2 3 1
```

So in this example, the three 1s have the lowest sum total, and none of them are in the same column or row, so the answer is the three 1s.

I could brute force this but that would take ages, does anyone have a smart solution? Pseudo code or a link to a suitable algorithm is fine by me.

Comment: I assume you already have a brute force solution in your favorite language and are only asking about optimisation idea. Please, show the code you have, tag the language and state whether this is a homework assignment. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I have not written a brute force method, as I believe that using an alternative (less accurate) solution to my problem would be preferable. I could write one to post however if you think that would help? I am not a student.

Comment: Showing your own coding attempts will win you some favors. People here are allergic to anything which can be mistaken as somebody just looking for a free coding service. Another favor can be won by taking the [tour].